# Как удалить из массива пары повторяющихся символов (зеркальных в том числе)? (PHP)

Tags: php, массивы

Например, есть массив `$arr = {"ia", "ai", "go", "og", "og", "cr", "og", "rc"}`

Как получить массив `$arr = {"ia", "go", "cr"}`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Грунди постоянно использует array_reduce(), попробовал сваять на нем:

```
$arr = ["ia", "ai", "go", "og", "og", "cr", "og", "rc"];

$new = array_reduce($arr, function ($acc, $item) {

    if (!in_array($item, $acc) && !in_array(strrev($item), $acc)) {
        array_push($acc, $item);
    }

    return $acc;

}, []);

print_r($new);
//Array ( [0] => ia [1] => go [2] => cr )
```

В работе https://3v4l.org/SYgPk

Comment: Спасибо большое =))

Answer (score -1):

- к массиву применяем метод [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php), где для каждого элемента применяем действия:

  ```
  $stringParts = str_split($item);
  sort($stringParts);
  return implode($stringParts);
  ```

  Это чтобы отсортировать символы в строке по алфавиту.
- Затем к массиву необходимо применить к массиву метод [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: не покатит. если без зеркальной, но буквы не по алфавиту, то перевернет строку, то есть для `['za']` вернет `['az']`, что наверное не корректно

Comment: @teran ....ммм?

Comment: @teran аааааааааа

Comment: Сейчас проверю, может так прокатит. Спасибо. Если есть ещё варианты, жду)).

Comment: @teran ну судя по окончательному выводу имено сортировка там и применяется, потому что в фиалке вывод не ia, а ai..... как мне показалось

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так они там все с зеркальным вариантом.  не ясно, какой вид должен быть, в противном случае

Comment: и собственно, если символов больше чем 3, то сортировка и зеркальный это разные вещи. нужно больше вводных.

Comment: Я хотел получить ia, go, cr.. Перепутал, сори.. но вроде как порядок не важен, главное, чтобы была уникальность

Comment: Но способ сложный для меня :D Я с callable ещё не  сталкивался, я нуб, а в array_map используется callable судя по руководству( Пытаюсь понять, что это такое.

Comment: анонимная функция, именованная функция или метод объекта. то что можно вызывать.